# how to get the sql sentence of the IQueryable and the ToList?

Tags: performance, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, iqueryable, ilist

I would like to know how I can get the sql sentence of an IQueryable and a Tolist.

I would like to compare this cases:

```
List<MyTable> lstresult01 = myContext.Mytable.Where(t=>t.ID == 1).ToList();

IQUeryable query = myContext.Mytable;
query = query.Where(t=>t.ID == 1);
List<MyTable> lstResult02 = query.ToList<MyTable>();
```

is faster the second one? I read that IQueryable is better because the conditions is send in the sql setence and IList don't do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Those 2 should be the same, but measure to be sure. You can't get the SQL after `ToList()`, only before.

Comment: and the seme is that is the best case? I mean if I get the advantage of the IQueryable?

Comment: No, the ToList() negates the deferred execution of the IQueryable.

Comment: To get the generated sql query, you either use a SQL profiler / EF Profiler to monitor the generated query. IQueryable does not send the query to the database unless you select something from the data or call ToList() kind of methods.